# Performance issue for Spark Sum and count

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I am pulling data from hive table and create a dataframe. And then do the sum and count operation. Data size is 3 TB approx.

Example

```
val DF1=hiveContext.sql("""SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4,count(col5) AS col5,
                           sum(col6) AS col6 from (
                                                  SELECT col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, 
                                                  sum(col6) AS col6 from <Dataframe from select fields from Table> 
                                                  group by col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
                                                  ) 
                           group by col1,col2,col3,col4
                        """)

DF1.count
```

This takes a lot of time. Could you please suggest the best possible approach for this scenario?

Comment: Your spark-UI log will be helpful to debug

Answer (score 0):

There can be 2 possible scenario

1. Your hive configuration and hardware is such that Hive itself takes a large amount of time to get outputs for the query
2. The Bandwidth/ or the Transport speed inter slave nodes is slow, so even after Hive executes the query quickly, due to slow speed of transfer of data from Hive to PySpark it takes a lot of time

Comment: Hive doesn't execute the query at all. `HiveContext` is used only to query metastore.